# Continuing Interactive Animation on Mouse Release (Actionscript 2.0)

Tags: flash, animation, actionscript, adobe, interactive

Hello first of all this is my first time I created a discussion so please forgive me if I posted this in a wrong area :)

So in the past few weeks I started to work with *Adobe Flash Professional CS6* and a little bit with *Actionscript*.
Due to another forum I was able to create my desired interactive turntable animation which you can see on [this linked website](http://silencedanger.deviantart.com/art/Interactive-3D-Figure-Animation-686278386).
Though I'm not completely satisfied with the result, as my animation ends very abruptly.

I actually want it to continue for some frames when I release the mouse button like in [this linked example](http://silencedanger.deviantart.com/art/Gameboy-Classic-3D-Turntable-180868177), so I asked the person what specific code he used but he seems to be inactive. In the comment section he only wrote that he used *Actionscript 2.0* to achieve this effect.

I hope anyone can help me with this problem as I simply can't figure out how to achieve the desired effect.

Here is the code I used in my example with *Actionscript 2.0*:

```
mc.stop();
var startX:Number;
var startFrame:Number;
var changeDistance:Number;
var travelDistance:Number;

mc.onPress = pressHandler;
mc.onRelease = releaseHandler;
mc.onReleaseOutside = releaseHandler;

function pressHandler():Void {
startX = mc._xmouse;
startFrame = mc._currentframe;
this.onMouseMove = moveHandler;
}

function releaseHandler():Void {
this.onMouseMove = null;
}

function moveHandler():Void {
changeDistance = Math.round((mc._xmouse - startX) / 15);
travelDistance = startFrame + changeDistance;
if (travelDistance > mc._totalframes) {
mc.gotoAndStop(travelDistance % mc._totalframes);
} else if (travelDistance < 0) {
mc.gotoAndStop(mc._totalframes + (travelDistance % mc._totalframes));
} else {
mc.gotoAndStop(travelDistance);
}
}
```

I really appreciate your time and thank you very much already ;)

Comment: You need to animate after you release, which means you set the destination in `moveHandler()`, and handle animation in a recurring function such as http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as2/reference/flashlite/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118cd9b5f6e-786c.html.  After you release, your `enterFrame` function will continue to be called, until it reaches its destination.  Some concept of acceleration, and velocity (or an easing function) will help in smoothing the approach to stop.

Comment: That seems very plausible :) Thank you very much @Atriace, I will definitely try it.